# Issues with raw_post_data decoding in Django

Tags: django

I have stumbled on a strange issue that I can't resolve:

In my Django app there is a method which gets hit by a POST from a java applet, which sends it a JSON object.  Django method parses it like so:

```
req = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
```

and based on the results returns a value. I haven't written this code, but yesterday I was sent to investigate an error triggered in this method. It was saying there was "ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)".

What I discovered is that my raw post data looks like this:

```
{#012#011"ImmutableMachineFactors": #012#011{#012#011#011"machineName": "lukka",#012#011#011"osName": "MacOS"}}
```

The type of it was string, however, my attempts to replace these weird characters with spaces or nothing failed.  It would just ignore the sub() command.  I know that raw_post_data returns a bytestring, but when I tried to convert it to a regular string using:

```
mystring.decode('utf-8')
```

it did add the u'' notation, but didn't remove those weird characters.  Stranger still, in many cases (on my personal machine), Django would happily convert this kind of data into JSON, it only fails sometimes, which led me to believe that the JSON which triggered the error was malformed, but when I would strip out all the #011 and #012 characters, it parsed perfectly.

My questions are:
1) What are those crazy things?  (#011, #012).  I tried to google around, but these are very common things to find in a search, so I couldn't find anything relevant.
2) How can I turn this bytestring into a regular string so that I can replace those characters? Or is it the wring way to approach this problem?

Thanks!
Luka

Comment: I can answer your first question, but am myself having problems with the 2nd part... which led me to find your post. So, the #012, for example, is the ascii Oct value for a newline, or \n, while #011 is the ascii Oct value for a tab, or \t. (see http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This may be way too late to help, but since QueryDict instances (request.POST or request.DATA) are immutable, it's reasonable to expect that request.raw_post_data is also immutable. You'd have to make a copy before changing it.